# command line parsing using apache commons cli

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

M tryng to use apache commons cli , My use case is variable number of arguments with some options.

Say

```
 -p str1 str2;
```

It can be

```
 -p str1 str2 str3 .. strn
```

Another is

```
 -m str1
 -h
```

with

```
 cmdline.getOptionValues("p");
```

It fetches only last string.How can I fetch all the values of an particular option?

Edit:

```
if(cmdline.hasOption("p")){
 String[] argsList = cmdline.getOptionValues(p);
  String strLine = Arrays.toString(argsList);
  argsList = strLine.split(",");
 }
```

M i doing it right? will string consist of exactly data I want or smthng unexpected white spaces r anythng else?

Comment: Please post the full code that you are using, including constructing of your parser and options.

Comment: Why are you stuffing the array into a String using Arrays.toString() and then splitting it back out? Please post the full code that you are using so that we can see what options, etc. and so that others may benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `hasArgs()` with a value separator set to a comma, so the option becomes

```
-p str1,str2,str3,...,strn
```

This is how multi-valued options are handled in CLI

Comment: hey m able to separate strings bt m gettng unexpected result later on like comparing it returns false where expected is true.I will post code hw m fetchng strings

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question for this instead of modifying the current question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're doing and where "it returns false", but this should work and I think do what you're trying to do.

```
final CommandLineParser cmdLinePosixParser = new PosixParser();
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("p").hasArgs().create("p"));
CommandLine commandLine = cmdLinePosixParser.parse(options, args);
if (commandLine.hasOption("p")) {
    String[] pArgs = commandLine.getOptionValues("p");
    System.out.println(pArgs.length);
    for (String p : pArgs) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```