# Commons CLI with dynamic number of arguments

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to create a java program which accepts dynamic number of arguments. For example:

```
java -jar my-utility.jar -l list1 list2 ... listN
```

where `N` may vary.

I'm using [Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/index.html) as the command line options parser. But I couldn't find a way to implement an [Option](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html) that accepts dynamic number of arguments.

[setArgs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html#setArgs-int-) specifies the number of arguments an option must take. Is it possible to specify the minimum number of arguments an option can take?

Or should I use other tools for parsing the command line options?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261629/command-line-parsing-using-apache-commons-cli

Answer (score 0):

You can pass "Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES" to setArgs to allow a variable number of arguments, like so:

```
Option p = new Option("p");
p.setArgs(Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES);
```

And then access them like so:

```
cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
String[] opts = cmd.getOptionValues("p");
```